# Lévy metric and distribution function

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I would like to know how to prove that the set of distribution functions with the modified Lévy metric, known as the Sibley metric, is a compact space. Sibley gave a proof in his 1972 article but it's hard for me to follow that proof.

Thanks in advance

ps: I'm a MSc student from the Sorbonne University. The question is related to my master's dissertation on Menger spaces.

Comment: in french  :comment prouver que l'espace des fonctions de distributions muni de la la distance modifié de levy connue sous le nom de distance de Sibley est un espace compact .La demo que donne Sibley dans son article est dur a comprendre et trop courte a mon sens

Comment: c'est dans me cadre de mon memoire de master sur les espaces de Menger

Comment: At least you should provide the article in question.

Comment: https://www.projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250131815.  But I understand the OP's difficulty -- I don't see how Helly's theorem plus Theorem 2 of the paper by Sibley "immediately" shows compactness.

Comment: is there anybody who can help  me because the due date is tomorow and i still don't undertsand the proof

Comment: @MinkowskiYaacov Let $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\Delta$. By [Helly's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_selection_theorem) there exists an $F\in \Delta $ and a subsequence of $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $F_{n_k}\rightarrow F$ weakly. By Theorem 2 of the article, $F_{n_k}\rightarrow F$ with respect to the modified Levy metric $\mathcal{L}$ as well. So $(\Delta, \mathcal{L})$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks a   lot  @treedetective  you've been very helpful .